# How to hide C++ private field/methods from autocomplete popup on QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to hide C++ private field/methods from autocomplete popup on QtCreator?

Although I saw [the bug report for QtCreator 2.0](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1984), Does the same problem still exist on QtCreator3.0? Is there any workaround for this problem? Any help would be apprecated. Thanks in advance.

[Example code]

```
// SomeClass.h
class SomeClass{
public:
void methodA();

private:
int fieldB;
void methodB();
}

//main.cpp

int main()
{
 SomeClass obj;
      ______________
 obj.|fieldB       | <- Popup window appears when '.' key is entered.
     |methodA()    | // I want to hide private fieldB and methodB from the popup  
     |methodB()    | // if possible.
     |_____________|
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B

Its just so you have the 'private member pointer' to a struct/class that defines all that should be hidden from the user of your class. and it is one member that is really private, the rest should then be public or inherited.

and it was designed to reduce compile time with the side effect of having a clear interface. also `Qt` uses it a lot via d-ptr pattern. http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer

cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It is good alternative solution for my question. So I accept your answer.

Comment: Opaque pointer has it's uses, but somehow I have an impression that getting right stuff (mostly) in the IDE hints is not one of the reasons behind it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no such functionality in qt creator as of now. As bug report comments point out, it might get rather difficult to tell what is accessible from where - mostly because friend classes/functions, inheritance and `protected`, templates. Qt creator would really have to include fully standard-compliant parser, which would probably be way too much - latest creator starts to work rather sluggish on more complex projects for me already.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand what you said.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. And hey, there is no need for that!

Probably "since the begining of the history" developers use simplest trick one can imagine. They choose specific prefix for all private fields. Some choose `m_` but i'd rather recommend you using simply `_` since it's least probable someone starts a name of "normal" function with. So adjust your definition of class to

```
class SomeClass{
public:
void methodA();

private:
int _fieldB;
void _methodB();
}
```

Oh, and also QtCreator is smart: all matching symbols will be at the bottom of the list. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I think it's nice idea to use private member  with specific prefix.